# mysql query search in left join that have condition related to a column

Tags: mysql, search, left-join

I have two tables (**A** & **B**):

table **A**:

```
+----+--------+
| id | title  |      
+----+--------+
|  1 | white  | 
|  2 | blue   | 
|  3 | red    | 
|  4 | white  |
|  5 | blue   | 
+----+--------+
```

table **B**:

```
+----+---------+------+------+
| id | content | A_id | type | 
+----+---------+------+------+
|  1 | dog     |    1 | good |
|  2 | dog     |    1 | bad  | 
|  3 | cat     |    2 | good | 
|  4 | cat     |    2 | bad  | 
|  4 | cat     |    2 | ugly | 
|  6 | crow    |    3 | good | 
|  7 | crow    |    3 | bad  |  
|  8 | crow    |    3 | ugly |  
|  9 | mouse   |    2 | good |  
| 10 | zebra   |    3 | bad  |  
|    |         |      |      | 
+----+---------+------+------+
```

result for this query:

```
SELECT A.*, B.content, B.type FROM A
LEFT JOIN B ON A.id=B.A_id
WHERE B.content='dog' OR B.content='cat' OR B.content='crow'
ORDER BY A.id ASC;
```

would be:

```
+----+-------+---------+------+
| id | title | content | type | 
+----+-------+---------+------+
|  1 | white | dog     | good |  
|  1 | white | dog     | bad  | 
|  2 | blue  | cat     | good | 
|  2 | blue  | cat     | bad  | 
|  2 | blue  | cat     | ugly |  
|  3 | red   | crow    | good | 
|  3 | red   | crow    | bad  | 
|  3 | red   | crow    | ugly | 
+----+-------+---------+------+
```

This resut for:

id=1 has **two types**:

`good` and `bad` but for

id=2 and id=3 has **three types**:

`good`, `bad` and `ugly`.

instead of above result I want a query that only give that ids that have common types in `id=1 and id=2 and id=3`. that means if for `id=1` results types are `good` and `bad` for `id=2 and 3` the rows that have type=`ugly` should be neglected.
I Want a query that give me this result:

```
+----+-------+---------+------+
| id | title | content | type | 
+----+-------+---------+------+
|  1 | white | dog     | good |  
|  1 | white | dog     | bad  | 
|  2 | blue  | cat     | good | 
|  2 | blue  | cat     | bad  |   
|  3 | red   | crow    | good | 
|  3 | red   | crow    | bad  | 
+----+-------+---------+------+
```

Comment: how can `WHERE A.title='doge' OR A.title='cat' OR A.title='crow'` give you any result ??? There is nothing matching this condition

Comment: That is my question. I want add some condition to give me a result that mentioned at the end of the question.

Comment: what you want ? clarify

Comment: The above query could not give you the third table since `'doge'` value does not exists in table `A`. Actual result is empty result set. The `title` column contains only "colors" not "animals"

Comment: in result table for id(A.id)=1 the result contains two rows that have two types 'good & bad'. for id(A.id)=2 & 3 the rows are three that have three types 'good, bad & ugly'. I want a query that give that their type is common in all ids. that means the type 'ugly' there is not in id=1 rows should be neglected in rows that have id=2 & 3. the condition shout not be such a thing: b.type!='ugly'. the query should neglect uncommon types.

Comment: But what if there is tie between 2 matches like dog has good & bad  cat has good & ugly , crow has good,bad & ugly now which rows will be returned with good,bad pair or good,ugly pair ?

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 1):

A bit hackish way for what you are trying to achieve

```
select A.*,B.*
from B
cross join(
  select 
  group_concat(type) all_types,
  count(distinct type) type_count
  from B
  where B.content IN('dog','cat','crow')
  group by content, A_id
  order by type_count
  limit 1
) B1
join A on A.id = B.A_id
where B.content IN('dog','cat','crow')
and find_in_set(b.type,B1.all_types) >0
```

[Demo](http://rextester.com/RTQMN28823)

First inner query will get the [lowest distinct types](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2d294/2) as comma separated list using `group_concat` that matched in table `B` by using limit 1 to pick the lowest set.

In outer query used that type set from previous inner query to include only rows that has these types only

Comment: @esmaeilsoomari nope its not complete solution i have posted a comment on post for a tie condition